# Mounted Dir 64% full but has no files or any related processes running

Tags: lvm, disk-usage

I have a directory that is for some reason 64% full but has no files or related processes open that can cause that space to be used

```
[root@exlap932 data02]# du -sh 
8.0K    .

[root@exlap932 data02]# ls -ltra
total 16
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 Oct 27  2014 .snapshot
drwxrwxrwx  3 root root 4096 Jul 15 07:12 .
drwxr-xr-x 27 root root 4096 Jul 15 07:53 ..

[root@exlap932 .snapshot]# du -sh 
4.0K    .


[root@exlap932 /]# df -h 
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_root-lv_root
                      2.0G  720M  1.2G  39% /
/dev/mapper/vg_root-lv_tmp
                      2.0G   74M  1.8G   4% /tmp
S259951CH3NAS05:/S259951CH3VOL15
                      4.0T  2.5T  1.5T  64% /data02

[root@exlap932 data02]# /usr/sbin/lsof | grep deleted 
vmtoolsd   2133      root    7u      REG              253,1     9858     229379 /tmp/vmware-root/appLoader-2133.log (deleted)
python     9615      root    3w      REG              253,3     1198     229393 /var/opt/opsware/agent/batch.381921880010.stdout (deleted)
python     9615      root    4w      REG              253,3        0     229397 /var/opt/opsware/agent/batch.381921880010.stderr (deleted)
python     9616      root    3w      REG              253,3     1198     229393 /var/opt/opsware/agent/batch.381921880010.stdout (deleted)

[root@exlap932 data02]# /usr/sbin/lsof | grep /data02
bash      23676 mhussaini  cwd       DIR               0,21     4096         64 /data02 (S259951CH3NAS05:/S259951CH3VOL15)
sudo      24675      root  cwd       DIR               0,21     4096         64 /data02 (S259951CH3NAS05:/S259951CH3VOL15)
su        24691      root  cwd       DIR               0,21     4096         64 /data02 (S259951CH3NAS05:/S259951CH3VOL15)
bash      24692      root  cwd       DIR               0,21     4096         64 /data02 (S259951CH3NAS05:/S259951CH3VOL15)
lsof      26968      root  cwd       DIR               0,21     4096         64 /data02 (S259951CH3NAS05:/S259951CH3VOL15)
grep      26969      root  cwd       DIR               0,21     4096         64 /data02 (S259951CH3NAS05:/S259951CH3VOL15)
lsof      26970      root  cwd       DIR               0,21     4096         64 /data02 (S259951CH3NAS05:/S259951CH3VOL15)
```

Comment: Do you know how the file server S259951CH3NAS05 is configured? It's common for file servers to export just a subtree of a more extensive filesystem. The administrator of the server ought to be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

`lsof` is only able to detect files deleted by processes running on the current file system. The file system mounted on `/data2` belongs to a remote file system so `lsof` is unaware of potential access by other clients, or by processes running on the file server itself.

Moreover, there is a `.snapshot` directory which suggests a file system like `ZFS` is used. In such case, the used space might simply belong to another file system sharing the same underlying pool.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I think you misused the command lsof.
For the result of df, it shows a report of **file system disk space usage**. For the result of lsof, it shows **which processes open the file or directory**.
The way that decreases your file system usage(the 64% full) is to **mount the file system and remove the unuseful files**.
For example:

`mount S259951CH3NAS05:/S259951CH3VOL15 /mnt
rm /mnt/unuseful
umount /mnt`